# storing/caching large objects for session for WCF

Tags: sql-server, wcf, caching

I have wcf webservice which is acting as B2B service. Basically I have suppliers and partners.
Here is how my WCF service works;
1) My service gets the products from several different suppliers by doing async webservice requests. 
2) Saves these products into a SQL server table. SQL server is on different server in the same LAN. 
3) Fetches the products from the DB and converts to the response object.
4) Finally returns the soap response.

My question is saving into DB is an expensive process as my requirement increases by adding new partners. I save those products only for purchase because I have 2 hours session timeout for my shopping basket and I want these products to be valid for 2 hours. I mean not the products in the shopping basket but all products. So within 2 hours they can be selected.
For my webservers I have 4 servers clustered but all uses 1 SQL server. What alternative can be a better solution for me? maybe a local DB? some kind of memory cache?

thanks for your advises.

Comment: Memory cache will provides best performance over the local database.

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota but on the other hand if memory gets overloaded, It may cause a low performance. Because I am talking about many concurrent sessions.

Comment: Do a math (Number of caches) * (Size of caches) < (Server Memory / Resources).Refer Azure Cache it can hold from 128MB all the way to 150 GB.http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/30/instant-azure-caching-with-mvc.aspx